# Как сделать перенос данных из одной страницы на другую в автоматическом режиме

Tags: php, javascript, веб-программирование, drupal

Есть одна таблица на одной странице сайта, в ней содержатся определённые данные. Есть другая таблица на другой странице. Вторая таблица содержит 1 столбец из первой таблицы. Как сделать так, чтобы при изменении данных в первой таблице изменённые данные во второй таблице автоматически изменились.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: Данную задачу, вопрос, можно решить при помощи socket-ов

Comment: Создайте таблицы вьюсами, в ней данные - тип материала с cck-полями, меняете материалы - в таблицах соответственно меняются данные.